# Form password entry not registering as post variable

Tags: php, html

Would appreciate some help! For some reason, the password entered into the form field:

```
<div>Confirm Password</div>
<input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" maxlength="100">
```

Is not registering in the php code below when it comes to grabbing it as a POST variable:

```
$p2 = $_POST['password2'];
```

The the php code above is above the html form if that matters... and the form posts to update.php which is the name of the file both of these pieces of code are in.

Comment: Show your whole form. You may be using the same field name twice.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['password2'])){ $p2 = $_POST['password2']; }` - which if not doing an `isset()` anywhere, would not show up on initial page load, along with other comments left. Harder to say without seeing full code.

Comment: As mentioned, update question with whole form markup. Or check: form `method` (should be `POST`), input `name` is unique, you're using most recent html and php code (i.e. you've saved/uploaded files).

Comment: In your form method data transfer is post? Like that `<form action="" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this

```
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
<input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" maxlength="100">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And on your somewhere.php, you can check

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$p2 = $_POST['password2'];
}else{echo "sorry form not submitted";}
```

Comment: Better to use `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){`